# Transcode from .ogg to .mp3 using VLC media player command line

Tags: audio, command-line, vlc-media-player

I am trying to do a command line convert from a .ogg file to a .mp3 file. Here is my command line:

> vlc -I dummy 0.ogg
>   --sout=#transcode{acodec=mp3,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:standard{access=file,mux=raw,dst=0.mp3}

I am getting the following error:

> main stream out error: Failed to create audio filter
>
> stream_out_transcode stream out error: Failed to find conversion
>   filter for resampling
>
> stream_out_transcode stream out error: cannot create audio chain
>
> main decoder error: cannot create packetizer output (vorb)

I have the ogg vorbis codecs installed.

Comment: (A) You have not given nearly enough information; (B) this would be more suitable for superuser.

Comment: What more possible information could I give ?  I am using Windows?

Comment: At the very least, show your environment, and where your codecs are installed. It might also be good to have any relevant config files. Lastly, confirm what command processor you are using.

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to have been asked/answered before elsewhere, http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=96894 Apparently, you just need to remove the samplerate part.

sneetchalizer also seems to be quite capable also, 
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/easy-way-to-convert-ogg-vorbis-to-mp3-on-fedora-484356/